Can anyone explain the analytic prismatization construction idea? And, what motivation do we have to construct it?
Recently, I've been exploring analytic stacks and prismatic cohomology, attempting to grasp the foundational concepts through this spring's notes on analytic prismatization over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ from the University of Chicago. However, I discovered that this differed from my initial concept of "turning prisms into stacks." As my understanding deepened, I found myself perplexed by the origins of some of these concepts. If anyone has insights into the ideas and motivations behind analytic prismatization, I would appreciate learning about them. Thanks in advance!

Are there notes somewhere? If so, could you please share them. I am only aware of Carmago's talk series at Chicago.

There is no I've been looking on the Internet lately, and perhaps this note from the University of Chicago is the only paper document on analytic prismatization,the rest are videos of lectures.

What is the 'note from the University if Chicago'? Could you share this please?

I refer to the notes in the analytic prismatization over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ mentioned in the question,I've already sent it to your email.If you have any ideas about this, please write them here, thank you very much!

Hi. Could you share the notes on analytic prismatization please?
